# Ajax There is any way or alternative for this?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to ask if there is any way to make this work:

```
         $.ajax({
             type : "POST",
             url : "process.php",
             data : $("#numberform").serialize(),
             success : function(data) {
                 if(data==true){
                  alert("Thats the right number");
                  }
                   else{
                    alert("Thats the wrong number);
                   }
             }
         });
```

Process.php

```
if(isset($_POST['number'])){
$numb=$_POST['number'];

if($numb=="1"){
     return true;
   }
   else{
  return false;
        }
}
```

Is possible to do anything like this?
I want to see the returned data from the ajax call on success.

Comment: Echo something in your script.

Comment: `if(return==true)` should be `if (data==true)`.  ofc, I know nothing about php so it may be that your process.php is not returning true/false correctly, but that's clearly wrong in the js.

Comment: I'd suggest you return JSON and then check a property of the resulting object in your JS code.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the returned data with this code on success function

```
success : function(data) {
             console.log(data);
         }
```

This may print json format. You choise a key that wish.

More details about php response
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4064468/6657711